# Combine two text files only for common values of a certain column

Tags: python

I have two text files:

text1.txt:

```
jose     50    0.037
maria    30    
fernando 20    0.489
martin   45    0.078
andres   47
```

text2.txt:

```
maria    150    0.91
martin   200    0.76
andres   350    0.67
```

I would like to reproduce this one:

```
maria    150    0.91    30    
martin   200    0.76    45    0.078
andres   350    0.67    47
```

that is to say, a combined file containing only values from common elements in the first column. Thanks.

Comment: Did something go wrong with the program you wrote to do this which we could help you with?  Please post your code and describe what's wrong with it.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you should select all the rows that are in both files, then concatenate the columns together.  Pandas would be very helpful here.

Comment: note that the `join text2.txt text1.txt` shell command does exactly what you want, though it requires the input files be sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two dictionaries from each input source to use to check for common names:

```
d1 = (lambda x:{a:b for a, *b in x})([i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('file1.txt')])
d2 = (lambda x:{a:b for a, *b in x})([i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('file2.txt')])
with open('file3.txt', 'w') as f:
  for a, b in d1.items():
     if a in d2:
        f.write(f"{a} {' '.join(d2[a]+b)}\n")
```

Output:

```
maria 150 0.91 30
martin 200 0.76 45 0.078
andres 350 0.67 47
```